# How to get NSManagedObject from NSNotification after iCloud sync

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I need to run updates based on when a NSManagedObject gets inserted/updated in the iCloud NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification. I need to get an attribute from the NSManagedObject that was updated/inserted named "url". Here's the code that I have so far...

```
//called when there is a change to iCloud data
- (void)cloudChanges:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [info objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [info objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [info objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];

    /*this is where i need to loop thru the objects and do something
    based on the url attribute of the NSManagedObject, the classname is ItemMeta
    */
    for (NSManagedObject *object in updatedObjects) {
        if ([[object entity].name isEqualToString:@"ItemMeta"]) {         
           // NSDictionary *entityDic = [object entity];
            //NSDictionary *changesDic = [object changedValues];
            //NSLog(@"changesDic.url: %@", [changesDic objectForKey:@"url"]);

            ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta *)[object entity];
           //this line throws an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"
            NSArray *itemMetas = [self getAllItemMetadataForURL:itemMeta.url];

        }
    }
```

***here's the update to correctly iterate the NSUpdatedObjectsKey Jun 6 2014

```
     for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in updatedObjects) {
            NSManagedObject *object = [self.mocMaster objectWithID:objectID];
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[ItemMeta class]]) {
                ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta *)object;
                NSArray *itemMetas = [self getAllItemMetadataForURL:itemMeta.url];
            }
        }
```

***end of update June 6 2014

```
    [self.mocMaster mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really ask a question or say what the issue with your code is.  Nonetheless:

`ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta *)[object entity];`

really ought to be:

<strike>`ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta *)object;`</strike>

`ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta*)[self.mocMaster objectWithID:object]`

`entity` is more of a class description, not an object instance.  <strike>`object` is the object instance that you need to cast to the entity class type.</strike> `object` turns out to be an `NSManagedObjectID` for iCloud notifications.

You could also use `[object isKindOfClass:[ItemMeta class]]` -- no chance for a typo in a string literal.

**You should probably do the `mergeChange` first,** as well, so that you get the updated object.

Comment: if I just cast the object to my class I get an error when trying to access an attribute
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID url]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd000000064600010'

Comment: It must be giving you NSManagedObjectIDs despite you casting as NSManagedObject ... `ItemMeta *itemMeta = (ItemMeta*)[self.mocMaster objectWithID:object]` ? You would ideally also change the type cast in your loop.

Comment: @JonathanRatcliff yeah... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317455/accessing-deleted-objects-in-icloud-notification) shows code to that effect.

Comment: I misunderstood what objects were being returned by userInfo. I changed it to use the NSManagedObjectID and get the NSManagedObject from there. Also important to note that this doesn't work well for NSDeletedObjectsKey as the related NSManagedObject may already be deleted, so trying to get them with objectWithID will cause issues. I'll update my post with the corrected code